Element is possibly undefined in TypeScript
I have this code in a React app with TypeScript.
 
const canvasRef = useRef<HTMLCanvasElement>();

useEffect(() => {
  const canvas = canvasRef.current;
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  //                 ^^^^^^^^^^ 'canvas' is possibly 'undefined'
}, [])

I get an error

'canvas' is possibly 'undefined'

How to solve this error.

The issue pertains to TypeScript, not Next.js, (contrary to what was initially posted before editing).
The message indicates that canvasRef.current might be undefined, which can occur if it is not passed as a ref prop to an element.
When you hover over the canvas, it shows the type as HTMLCanvasElement | undefined. The getContext method exists in HTMLCanvasElement but not when it's undefined. Therefore, you must verify that canvas is not undefined before trying to access any properties or methods.

by the ? operator:

canvas?.getContext("2d")


or by early return:

  const canvas = canvasRef.current;
  
  if (!canvas) return;

  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

Don't forget to pass the canvasRef as a ref prop to your <canvas /> element.

nice done well. so good. Thanks.
